# Users cant see custom objects. That are connected to the Standard object via master detail relationship

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, opportunity-lineitem

Some of my users can't seem to access a custom object that is master detailed to an opportunity section. [image]
Does anyone know how to fix it ? Only system administrators can see it.

Comment: Have you given read permission to the detail object for the users at the profile or permission set level?

Comment: yes we've tried that It's something separating it from normal users

Comment: is the related list on the page layout that are assigned to those users?

Comment: Are the sharing rules on your custom object set to inherit from the parent object?

Comment: Everything is assigned to all users. The sharing rules are also set up.